# Write a program that reads a string and a number and outputs the word from the position indicated by the number

Tags: c#, string

I need an idea.
This is what I tried:

```
string text = Console.ReadLine();
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
char[] mychar = { ' ' };
int n = 0;
string[] wordslist = text.Split(mychar);
foreach (char in text)
 n = n+1;
if (n+1<number)
    Console.WriteLine("N/A");
else
    Console.WriteLine(wordslist[number-1]);
```

If the number inputted is bigger than the number of words from string it should return "N/A".
It works if I don't use the foreach loop for number lower or equal with the words number.

Answer (score -2):

```cs
var text = Console.ReadLine();

int number;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);

var words = text.Split(' ');
if(words.Count > number)
{
  Console.WriteLine(words[number]);
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("N/A");
}
```

This sounds like homework...

Comment: ... and you just did it for them. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) Putting *more* explanation into answers of homework questions is the better tactic.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer and add an explanation...

Comment: @Sidereus The `foreach` loop and `n` variable aren't necessary. You simply need to read the `number`th index in the `wordslist`, as demonstrated in this answer

Comment: Uh... what if _words.Count_ is exactly equal to _number_?

Comment: The index in `IEnumerable`s is zero-based, so getting this value would throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. This code is safe since `number < words.Count` when looking up the value. However, you could expand the check to see if `0 <= number` too...